# I need a SQL query for comparing column values against rows in the same table

Tags: sql

I have a table called `BB_BOATBKG` which holds passengers travel details with columns `Z_ID`, `BK_KEY` and `PAXSUM` where:

```
Z_ID = BookingNumber* LegNumber
BK_KEY = BookingNumber
PAXSUM = Total number passengers travelled in each leg for a particular booking
```

For Example:

```
Z_ID         BK_KEY     PAXSUM
001234*01   001234           2
001234*02   001234           3
001287*01   001287           5
001287*02   001287           5
002323*01   002323           7
002323*02   002323           6
```

I would like to get a list of all Booking Numbers `BK_KEY` from `BB_BOATBKG` where the total number of passengers `PAXSUM` is different in each leg for the same booking
Example, For Booking number `A`, `A*Leg01` might have 2 Passengers, `A* Leg02` might have 3 passengers

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Dependent of your RDBMs there might be several options availible. A solution that should work for most is:

```
SELECT A.Z_ID, A.BK_KEY, A.PAXSUM
FROM BB_BOATBKG A
JOIN ( 
    SELECT BK_KEY
    FBB_BOATBKGROM BB_BBK_KEY
    GROUP BY BK_KEY
    HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT PAXSUM ) > 1
) B
    ON A.BK_KEY = B.BK_KEY
```

If your DBMS support OLAP functions, have a look at `RANK() OVER (...)`

Comment: Oh wait, I think you have an issue with this one: I'm pretty sure you need to *exclude* the `BK_KEY` values produced by the subselect instead of joining into them. The subselect determines which records have duplicate `PAXSUMS`, and those are the rejects.

Comment: I don't understand your remark, the OP wrote "I would like to get a list of all Booking Numbers BK_KEY from BB_BOATBKG where the total number of passengers PAXSUM is different in each leg for the same booking". In what way does my proposal violate this?

Comment: If you have an entry with three separate legs with `PAXSUM`s (1, 2, 2), your solution pulls back that entry because `COUNT(DISTINCT PAXSUM)` is indeed greater than 1. The constraint ends up needing to be something more akin to `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PAXSUM) = COUNT(*)`. (I tried that locally and it did work).

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Not sure that would be a false positive though. @user2380064: can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little counterintuitive, but you could join the table to itself on {BK_KEY, PAXSUM} and pull out only the records whose joined result is null.

I think this does it:

```
SELECT
    a.BK_KEY
FROM
    BB_BOATBKG a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN BB_BOATBKG b ON a.BK_KEY = b.BK_KEY AND a.PAXSUM = b.PAXSUM
WHERE
    b.Z_ID IS NULL
GROUP BY
    a.BK_KEY
```

Edit: I think I missed anything beyond the trivial case. I think you can do it with some really nasty subselecting though, a la:

```
SELECT
    b.BK_KEY
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            a.BK_KEY,
            Count = COUNT(*)
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    a.BK_KEY,
                    a.PAXSUM
                FROM
                    BB_BOATBKG a
                GROUP BY
                    a.BK_KEY,
                    a.PAXSUM
                HAVING
                    COUNT(*) = 1
            ) a
        GROUP BY
            a.BK_KEY
    ) b
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            c.BK_KEY,
            Count = COUNT(*)
        FROM
            BB_BOATBKG c
        GROUP BY
            c.BK_KEY
    ) c ON b.BK_KEY = c.BK_KEY AND b.Count = c.Count
```

Comment: Very similar to what I was going to offer, however, if there are 4 legs to a trip, and the counts go from 2, 3, 3, 2, what might be the correct answer...  But otherwise, right-on target by the ISNULL basis.  You might show the a. count compared to the b. count showing the differential.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I totally missed any case beyond the trivial. I think the second try handles all cases correctly, though it's less clever and elegant (the *true* measure of a solution :)

Comment: The query returns no records as i am sure that there are plnety of records in the table BB_BOATBKG\

Comment: If I include BK_KEY number 002325 with PAXSUM =1, in the above table BB_BOATBKG, The result set with the above query provided by "eouw0o83hf" will include                                   BK_KEY 002325 as well which have only one leg.                 BK_KEY PAXSUM                                                  001234 2                                                       001234 3                                                         002323 6                                                            002323 7                                                       002325 1

Comment: Is there anyway to exclude in the result set, the bookings with only one leg and include only those which has got more than one leg and among those legs, there is a difference in passengers in each leg? (Difference in PAXSUM)                                                             The result I expect here to have is only                                         
BK_KEY          PAXSUM
001234  2
001234  3
002323  6
002323  7

Comment: I think you can add a `WHERE c.Count > 1` at the very end of the whole query to filter out bookings with only one leg.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to modify the query so that the result set includes both BK_KEY and PAXSUM as well ?? Appreciate your help @ eouw0o83hf.

Comment: You should just be able to `INNER JOIN` again to `BB_BOATBKG` after the subselects to get whatever you need from that table again

Comment: @eouw0o83hf ,Please provide code for the query as i am getting errors with the INNER JOIN